# Can we batch rename excel variable names?

Tags: excel, vba

Image you have an excel sheet, with names as variables for formulas, references, etc. (all viewable the Names Manager).

You want to create clones of this sheet, and add them as separate sheets to another workbook.

However, the names will conflict.

E.g. FirstColumnTitle will be the same for each sheet.

Excel seems to latch the basic function to batch rename variable names in the Names Manager, so the same name can be renamed (e.g. append ‘_sheet1’ to  FirstColumnTitle making it ‘FirstColumnTitle_sheet1’).

How would one go about this?

I tried Names Manager, and a VB Macro (link below) that was supposed to work (but only renamed a single variable).

```
Sub RenameCells()
Dim n As Name
    For Each n In ThisWorkbook.Names
        n.Name = "KUTOOLS_" & n.Name
    Next n
End Sub
```

I can manually change the names one by one, but… what if there are hundreds of names on a sheet that will be cloned to the same workbook a handful of times?

Example: the sheet/worksheet is a loan amortization template. In the Template, it has names such as “LoanAmount” which refers to the cell where the loan amount is entered, and “LoanInterestRate” referring to the cell sign the APR.

If I try to copy that whole worksheet into another workbook twice (two different copies of the loan worksheet in two tabs in one workbook) the variable names (found in Names Manager) conflict with one another and end up interfering with one another or blocking calculations/functionality in one or the other worksheet (if they have different values.)

How to reproduce the problem (that I'm trying to solve):

1. Create a new spreadsheet from the "**Loan Amortization Schedule**" **template**,
2. then create a copy of that sheet a couple times to the same workbook (or another).
3. Now set a loan balance, APR, loan term, and payments per year (make it different for each sheet such that the number of payments should be different).

Notice that in the second (and third and fourth) sheet, the result for "Actual Number of Payments" for each sheet is whatever the value is for the first sheet. Open Names Manager, and the name for each indicates that its scope is only for the appropriate sheet, yet somehow sheet1's ActualNumberOfPayments reference name is referred to in the other sheets (even though their respective ActualNumberOfPayments appropriately refers to the other reference names in their own sheet only).

Comment: Can you post the exact VBA code you used?

Comment: Are your Names worksheet-level Names, or Workbook-level?

Comment: Post your code here please not a link

Comment: What does *"the names will conflict"* exactly mean? When you copy the worksheet as-is to another workbook, you'll have the same names as in the original.

Comment: A different approach would be to write code that creates all the names in the original worksheet. So if you deleted every name on that worksheet in Names Manager, that code could recreate all the names. After that, it should be easier to adapt the code to work on the new worksheets with whatever amendments you need to the names

Comment: Sorry, I’lol try to clarify here and above — the sheet/worksheet is a loan amortization template. In the Template, it has names such as “LoanAmount” which refers to the cell where the loan amount is entered, and “LoanInterestRate” referring to the cell sign the APR. if I try to copy that same worksheet to the same workbook (two different loan tabs in one workbook) the variable names conflict with one another and end up interfering with one another or blocking calculations/functionality in one or the other worksheet (if they have differ values.)

Comment: Your addition to the post (*"...but only renamed a single variable..."*) is proof that the remaining names are of worksheet-scope which also means that their *Name* property returns something like `Sheet1!MyName`.

Comment: In your post, you state that you want to *"add them as separate sheets to another workbook"* so why can't you just copy the worksheet to another workbook? Why is cloning in the same workbook so important?

Comment: If your named range in the Name Manager is worksheet scope and refers to different worksheet than you won't get a correct named range for the sheet which you don't copy. For example, your current workbook name is BLA.xlsm and in the Name Manager you have test1 refer to a range in sheet1 and test2 refer to a range in sheet2. You copy sheet1 as a new workbook. In the newly created workbook, if you check the Name Manager, the test2 will refer to BLA sheet2 something like this `=[BLA.xlsm]Sheet2!$A$1` while the test1 is like this `=Sheet1!$D$1`.

Comment: The VBA script I used (in the post) worked to rename a single name, but failed to rename the rest. All names were worksheet scope only. There were no workbook scope names for the script to get stuck on.

Comment: J.Doe, I don't think that the code you put in your question will fail to rename the rest. To me the code seems just renaming the name (by adding text "KUTOOLS_" in front of the old name), the code don't bother what is the reference range to each renamed name. You wrote _All names were worksheet scope only_ .... IF all names refer to the sheet that you copy, then I think there will be no problem. You wrote : _There were no workbook scope names_ ... even if there is, I think it still can't work if the workbook scope NamedRange is reffering to a range of other than the sheet you copy.

Comment: Thanks @karma, I'll have to keep playing around with it to see where it's going awry.